# Set time to call the method in Android

Tags: android, timer

I am developing an Android application.
I want to set a timer to call the method in my application.

For Example...
Call a method to send an SMS every 30 seconds.

How can I do that ? Please help?

Answer (score 2):

Use an Handler

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // call your method

        }
    }, 30000);
```

Comment: 30000 is milisecod,isn't it

Comment: yes it is. take a look to the documentaion

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Timer` to run the specific task after some time continously. Here is how you can implement the Timer.

```
Timer timer1 = new Timer();
            timer1.schedule(new AnimationTask(), 2000,5);
```

Implementing the `AnimationTask()`

```
class AnimationTask extends TimerTask
    {
        public void run()
        {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
            {
                 public void run() 
                 {
                     textAnim();
                 }
            });
        }
    }
```